# How to debug JCL internal error while submitting RUNJCL

Tags: mainframe, jcl

During the compilation of a COBOL program I got MAXCC=0, but while submitting the RUNJCL I got a JCL internal error. Does that mean I have an error in RUNJCL or a logical error in program? How to debug JCL INTERNAL ERROR?

Comment: It means you have a problem with the JCL. The JCL doesn't even get to run, it is discarded before that. Even a MAXCC=0 (presumably the message from a NOTIFY on the JOB card) has nothing to do with whether your program works, or will work. It simply means you got a clean compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your first job -- the compile of the program -- worked.

Your second job -- the attempt to run the program -- was never attempted.  A "JCL Error" is trapped because the commands in the job stream are somehow detected to be not valid before any execution is attempted.

Usually, this is because of a misplaced comma, an misspelled keyword, or a dataset name that is misspelled (read nonexistent in the form provided).  There are way too many possible conditions that could cause an internal JCL error to diagnose without more detail, but you should be able to find that detail in the job log.

Look at the output, really read the output, of the job.  At some point, my guess is you will find a 'missing dataset' or 'unknown keyword' error that prevented the job from ever attempting to run.

Since you failed to post your output, that is the best I can do, if you append your output, perhaps some more clarity can be given.